# read csv with pandas in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is the code that i'm using to read a csv file to Jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\File.csv")
for row in data:
    print(row)
    if len(data) > 5:
        break
```

I have also tried

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\File.csv")
```

which results to the following error

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-332200c5442e> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\File.csv")
      4 for row in data:
      5     print(row)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    446 
    447     # Create the parser.
--> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    449 
    450     if chunksize or iterator:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    879 
--> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    881 
    882     def close(self):

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1113         if engine == "c":
-> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1115         else:
   1116             if engine == "python":

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890 
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\File.csv does not exist: 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\File.csv'
```

- After trying

  import os

  if os.path.isfile('C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\File.csv'): 
            print('File Exists') 
     else: 
            print('File does not exists')

as suggested by @LittinRajan, i get that the file does not exist. Well, obviously the file does exist, and i'm using the correct path, so it could be something with Jupyter. Any help will be appreciated sine i am new to Python and Jupyter

Comment: file should be placed relatively to jupyter working directory, or should add explicite folders to jupyter comand. Or you should run jupyter command from C:/

Comment: @404pio absolute path should work nevertheless

Comment: Have you tried opening the file outside of jupyter? Either in an interactive session or from a .py file? This could help determine whether it's a jupyter specific issue

Comment: #First check whether the file is existing in the directory you specified.
import os
os.path.isfile('C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\File.csv')

Comment: Hi @LittinRajan i have tried your suggestion, and apparently the file does not exists, although i have copied the path from the actual file. This is strange because i have opened the same file (with the same path) using R. Do you have any idea why might be that?

Comment: Hi @Xristos Solwmou . The reason why you have to use 'r' in front of the filepath is to let the interpreter understand that it is a raw text or raw string that you mentioned in your path 'C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\File.csv'. If you don;t use the 'r' then the interpreter will consider the path differentiating backslashes in your file path as normal backslashes so it won;t get the path. So it's recommended to use 'r' before first quote of the filepath.  You can find the documentation from the link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings    I hope it would be helpful...  : )

Comment: No you did not understand me. I have opened the file using R, as the programming language R https://www.r-project.org/.  So the file does exist on my Desktop, and the file is correct. However, when i'm trying the method you suggested i get that the file does not exist. Any idea why?

Comment: So this if os.path.isfile('C:\\Users\\c_solomou\\Desktop\\TimeSeriesRest.csv'): 
        print('File Exists') 
else: 
            print('File does not exists') returns file does not exist

Comment: Could you please try the following two things: (1) os.path.isfile('C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/File.csv') (forward slash). (2) os.path.isfile(os.path.join("C:", "Users", "Mike", "Desktop", "File.csv"))

Comment: Hi @Roy2012, thank you for your reply. I have tried both of the methods that you suggested, and none of them works. Also, i have tried reading different csv files from my Desktop, and i get the same errors that files do not exist. Not sure what's going on

Comment: what happens when you run the same code (os.path.isfile, etc) from a 'regular' python script, outside of Jupyter?

Comment: I'm new to python and Jupyter is the first environment i am using so dunno

Comment: (1) Take the code from this url: https://codeshare.io/2BxM9m; (2) copy it into a text file (e.g. with notepad). (3) save it under the name test.py (4) open a cmd window, and run 'python test.py' (5) tell us what you got.

Comment: Thanks @Roy2012. Here it is :C:\Users\Mike\Desktop>python test.py
  File "test.py", line 3
    res = os.path.isfile('C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\File.csv')
                         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: seems like a copy-paste issue from my code to your machine. Are you sure you used just notepad, and not a more sophisticated editor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215524/discussion-between-xristos-solwmou-and-roy2012).